# For a shift matrix $A$, prove that $A^n=0$ but $A^{n-1} \neq 0$.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

> Let $A\in F_n$ be the matrix
>    $\begin{pmatrix} 0&1&0&0&\cdots&0 \\ 0&0&1&0&\cdots&0 \\ \vdots\\ 0&0&0&0&\cdots&0 \end{pmatrix}$, whose entries every, except on the superdiagonal, are 0, and whose entries on the superdiagonal are 1. Prove that $A^n=0$ but $A^{n-1}\neq 0$.

I'm not really sure where to begin with this problem. So far I've tried induction on the $A^n=0$ part, but I got stuck trying to show that if the result holds and $A^n=0$, then it implies that $A^{n+1}=0$.

Any hints would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $A e_{k+1} = e_k$, and $A = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & e_1 & e_2 & \cdots & e_{n-1} \end{bmatrix}$, we see that $A^2 = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & e_1 & \cdots & e_{n-2} \end{bmatrix}$, that is it 'shifts' the columns to the right and brings the zero vector in from the left. Hence $A^{n-1} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & e_{1} \end{bmatrix} \neq 0$, and $A^n = 0$.

Comment: how does one prove in general, though that $Ae_{k+1}=e_{k}$? By induction? And if so, induction on what? You've got both the matrix size $n$ and the $k$th basis vector.

Answer (score 2):

If $e_i$ is the $i$-th canonical vector note that $Ae_i$ equals $e_{i-1}$ if $i>1$ and 0 if $i=1$. Hence $A^{n-1}e_n=A^{n-2}e_{n-1}=...=Ae_2=e_1$. Hence $A^{n-1}\neq 0$ (its image is not zero, it takes every vector to is $n$-th entry).

Moreover, the same argument proofs that $A^n$ takes any canonical vector to zero. Hence every vector since they form a basis.